# Last 12 months in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, kendo-ui

I got an Kendo ui Chart like [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/area-charts/grouped-data.html) one and have to show the last 12 months of todays date on the axis. 
I found [this](http://dansnetwork.com/javascript-date-object-adding-and-subtracting-months/) to extend the date object to get the previous month. The problem seems to be when I got an Date like "2013/05/31" and the previous months got no 31st day.

```
Date.prototype.toPrevMonth = function (num) {
    var thisMonth = this.getMonth();
    this.setMonth(thisMonth-1);
    if(this.getMonth() != thisMonth-1 && (this.getMonth() != 11 || (thisMonth == 11 &&      this.getDate() == 1)))
    this.setDate(0);
}


new Date().toPrevMonth(11),
new Date().toPrevMonth(10),
new Date().toPrevMonth(9),
new Date().toPrevMonth(8),
new Date().toPrevMonth(7),
new Date().toPrevMonth(6),
new Date().toPrevMonth(5),
new Date().toPrevMonth(4),
new Date().toPrevMonth(3),
new Date().toPrevMonth(2),
new Date().toPrevMonth(1),
new Date().toPrevMonth(0)
```

Can anyone help me out with the if state?
 The function is build to show only the previous month, but I need the last 12 previous months.

Or is there a much easier solution? :-)

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Datejs (http://www.datejs.com/)

It has a built in function to add months:

```
Date.today().addMonths(-6);
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you're not able to include external files, here are the relevant methods from within Datejs.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2006-2007, Coolite Inc. (http://www.coolite.com/). All rights reserved.
 * License: Licensed under The MIT License. See license.txt and http://www.datejs.com/license/. 
 * Website: http://www.datejs.com/ or http://www.coolite.com/datejs/
*/

Date.isLeapYear = function (year) {
    return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0));
};

Date.prototype.isLeapYear = function () {
    var y = this.getFullYear();
    return (((y % 4 === 0) && (y % 100 !== 0)) || (y % 400 === 0));
};

Date.getDaysInMonth = function (year, month) {
    return [31, (Date.isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
};

Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth = function () {
    return Date.getDaysInMonth(this.getFullYear(), this.getMonth());
};

Date.prototype.addMonths = function (value) {
    var n = this.getDate();
    this.setDate(1);
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth() + value);
    this.setDate(Math.min(n, this.getDaysInMonth()));
    return this;
};
```

Comment: @chrisツ how about copying and pasting the source code of Datejs to your code. Just remember to include the copyright of the code.

Comment: LOL I was just working on doing that exact extraction to amend my answer.

Answer (score 17):

Including year of month

```js
var monthName = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(1);
for (i=0; i<=11; i++) {
    console.log(monthName[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear());
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
}
```

Comment: Please note that if your current date is for 29. of March, this method will return march two times, because 29/03/19 minus one month is 29/02/19, which does not exist, so it returns corresponding date in march instead (1/03).
So it is important that you start out by d.setDate(1) to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 10):

I also needed a list of the last 12 months this is what I did:

```
var theMonths = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var today = new Date();
var aMonth = today.getMonth();
var i;
for (i=0; i<12; i++) {
    document.writeln(theMonths[aMonth] + '<br>'); //here you can do whatever you want...
    aMonth++;
    if (aMonth > 11) {
        aMonth = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Last N(24) months incrementally - Important to show timeseries data

```js
var monthName = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
        var months = [];
        var d = new Date();
        d.setDate(1);
        for (i=0; i<=24; i++) {
//                console.log(monthName[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear());
            months.push(monthName[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getFullYear());
            d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
        }
        months = months.reverse();
        for (i=0; i<=24; i++) {
          console.log(months[i]); 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled it like so to output a new array `lastMonths` containing the last 12 months from today in order:

```
var date = new Date();
var lastMonths = [],
    monthNames = ['Dec', 'Nov', 'Oct', 'Sep', 'Aug', 'Jul', 'Jun', 'May', 'Apr', 'Mar', 'Feb', 'Jan'];
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    lastMonths.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()]);
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 1);
}

console.log(lastMonths);

// ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a function to work with various amounts of last months and the ability to exclude the current month

```
function getLastMonths(monthCount, excludeCurrentMonth) {
  //debugger;  
  var currentDate = new Date(); // Get the current date
  var months = []; // Array to store the last N months

  // if the current month should be excluded, off by default
  if(excludeCurrentMonth) {
      currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 1);
  }
    
  for (var i = 0; i < monthCount; i++) {
    var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth(); // Get the current month (0-11)
    var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear(); // Get the current year

    // Add the current month and year to the array
    months.unshift(currentYear + "-" + (currentMonth + 1) );

    // Move to the previous month
    currentDate.setMonth(currentDate.getMonth() - 1);
  }

  return months;
}

// Usage
var last12Months = getLastMonths(12);
console.log(last12Months);

var last12MonthsWithoutCurrentOne = getLastMonths(12, true);
console.log(last12MonthsWithoutCurrentOne);
```